# How can I get desktop icons to show on-screen with mismatched monitors?

Tags: gnome, nautilus, multiple-monitors, icons, shortcuts

My main monitor is on the left and in landscape orientation at 1680x1050.  My secondary monitor is on the right and in portrait orientation at 1050x1680.  So, overall, my desktop is treated as 2730x1680.  The left monitor is set approximately at the middle of the right one, so there are theoretically two invisible 265x1680 bars above and below the display area of the left monitor:

[image]

The problem is that when laying out desktop icons, it ignores the fact that those bars are off-screen.  So my icons start out off-screen and gradually come on-screen, then disappear off the bottom again before wrapping around ([see this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8VRG.png)).

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04, but [this bug](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=60280#c26) was reported at least as early as 2001.  [The suggested workaround](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/360970/comments/14) of using the fallback desktop rather than Unity is not working for me — as mentioned and as you can see from the screenshot linked above, the screen with the issue is my primary one and has the gnome panels on it.  I also tried manually adding panels to the top and left without any luck.

Is there any other workaround or fix for this issue?

Comment: I just installed Ubuntu 14.04, and I'm having the same problem now. Did you ever find a fix for this?

Comment: @Michael Sadly not.