# Can I double the Trash on Desktop?

Tags: trash, desktop-apps

I have a pretty weird question. **Can I double my Trash Icon?**
I need to double it because I have a laptop, and plan on getting a second monitor, so I need a trash icon there.

Comment: Will ubuntu automatically add an icon on the second monitor?                                            That thought just crossed my mind...

Comment: Not at my box, but can't you just make a symlin? In any case, a .desktop file can be made with same functionality, calling a script and using %u for drag and drop. Have done that in the past.

Comment: Wait, what is your distro/ version?

Comment: I use Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

Comment: wait, what is 'symlin'?

Comment: Ah, travelling by car, bumpy road :) I meant symlink.

Comment: If you won't manage, I'll post my .desktop file + script later.

Comment: @JacobVlijm Any luck with your python (I assume) script that duplicates icons across all screens? I'd like to have that too. I don't mean mirror desktop but across extended desktop. Bonus if app opens on which of the three (in my case) screens the icon was clicked on? Also consider this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/573769/how-can-i-get-desktop-icons-to-show-on-screen-with-mismatched-monitors

Comment: @JacobVlijm Kubuntu already has an option to duplicate icons across two screens but I'm using Unity not Gnome or KDE Plasma: https://askubuntu.com/questions/914905/desktop-icons-are-duplicated-on-both-screens